# bound two query in single query both data will be show

Tags: sql-server

Query 1:

```
select * from(select* from (select Product_ID, batchno, Baleno, 
SampleTime, Line, ItemData, ItemType from ItemData) d 
pivot(sum(ItemData) for ItemType in (DYL, COLOR, STD)) as piv1) ff 
where batchno = '001' AND Product_ID = '1' And Line = 'B'
```

Query 2:

```
select * from(select* from (select Product_ID, batchno, Baleno, SampleTime, 
Line, ItemData, ItemType from ItemData) d 
pivot(sum(ItemData) for ItemType in (DYL, COLOR, STD)) as piv1) ff 
where batchno = '001' AND Product_ID = '1' And Line = 'A'
```

Comment: As i have understood, you want to show all data from Line A and B from ItemData Table. so you can simply use UNION. if your requirement is something else, then please elaborate it.

Comment: As both query seems returning data in same structure, use UNION ALL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UNION ALL As below-

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Product_ID, 
               batchno, 
               Baleno, 
               SampleTime, 
               Line, 
               ItemData, 
               ItemType
        FROM ItemData
    ) d PIVOT(SUM(ItemData) FOR ItemType IN(DYL, COLOR, STD)) AS piv1
) ff
WHERE batchno = '001' AND Product_ID = '1' AND Line = 'B';

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Product_ID, 
               batchno, 
               Baleno, 
               SampleTime, 
               Line, 
               ItemData, 
               ItemType
        FROM ItemData
    ) d PIVOT(SUM(ItemData) FOR ItemType IN(DYL,  COLOR,  STD)) AS piv1
) ff
WHERE batchno = '001'  AND Product_ID = '1' AND Line = 'A';
```